# Character '\c' vs character 'c' in paths C++

Tags: c++, directory, path, character

I mean, it's kind of strange. I have a const char PATH = "hello\cpp\visualstudio\nano\sources" which represents a path to something. It can only contain small English letters and '\' (backslash) character. I need to find the folders in that path and i.e. to output each one on a new line. In my example, it would be:

hello

cpp

visualstudio

nano

sources

How can I do that? :) Can't find any solution...
If you don't know, in C++, any other character with '\' in front of it except '\a', '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t' and '\v' is the same without '\'. I mean '\c' is exactly the same with 'c'. Can't find when it's a new folder or not.

Can you please help me? :)

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you've tried so far? Also, the statement "'\c' is exactly the same with 'c' is not true. The latter is a character, the former is an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: Do you mean `"hello\\cpp\\visualstudio\\nano\\sources"`? You need to escape to backslashes.

Comment: 'find the folders in that path' -- Please review "Filesystem" library, i.e. "#include <filesystem>".  The other choice is OS dependent ... Linux does have functions easy to use, and fully C++ accessible.  Either way, Google is your friend.

Comment: I haven't tried something useful so far. And I mean: `const char PATH[101] = "hello\cpp\visualstudio\nano\sources";`

Comment: Please read the comment by @Yksisarvinen

Comment: I don't mean that.

Comment: @MarcVana Yes you do.  The string you are using is invalid, you need to double up the back slashes.

Comment: @MarcVana Then what do you mean? Why would you create a path without the directory separators?

Comment: Tip: avoid the problem altogether: `#include <filesystem> std::filesystem::path p = std::filesystem::path{"hello"} / "cpp" / "visualstudio" / "nano" / "sources";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the folders in that path and i.e. to output each one on a new line.

I suggest that you use the C++17 [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) that has support for splitting paths up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::vector<fs::path> separate(const fs::path& p) {
    std::vector<fs::path> rv;

    rv.push_back(p.filename()); // save only the basename part

    // iterate up to the paths root
    for(fs::path old = p, t = p.parent_path();
        t != old && not t.empty();
        old = t, t = t.parent_path())
    {
        rv.push_back(t.filename());
    }
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    std::filesystem::path path = std::filesystem::path{"hello"} / "cpp" / "visualstudio" /
                                 "nano" / "sources";

    for(const auto& p : separate(path)) {
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"sources"
"nano"
"visualstudio"
"cpp"
"hello"
```

If you want it in the reverse order, you can use the `vector`s `rbegin()` and `rend()` functions, or just reverse it in the `separate()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal): `R"raw(hello\cpp\visualstudio\nano\sources)raw";` *or* you could just use forward slashes, like on UNIX, which Windows supports just fine: `"hello/cpp/visualstudio/nano/sources";` *or* use [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Comment: Expanding a bit: the Windows (and DOS) command shell uses backslashes as directory separators. Everything else in Windows uses backslashes and forward slashes interchangeably, and anyone who seriously programs in Windows avoids those backslashes. +1.

Comment: Thank you! I found out that filesystem::path was what I was looking for!